# C0000005 Access violation while loading Windows DLL before entering main of C++

Tags: windows, dll, access-violation

I encounter a "First-chance exception", which is an "Access violation -code c0000005", when loading 3rdparty Windows DLL before entering my main function. Can we decide if the problem lies in my code or the 3rdparty code?

Below is the log from windbg:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.12.0002.633 X86
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

CommandLine: D:\risc\rlx_vm\trunk\msvc80\debug\test_rlxvm_ovpsim_dma_ocp_tl2.exe
Symbol search path is: D:\risc\rlx_vm\trunk\msvc80\debugwithreleasecrt;D:\risc\rlx_vm\trunk\msvc80\debug
Executable search path is: 
ModLoad: 00400000 008af000   test_rlxvm_ovpsim_dma_ocp_tl2.exe
ModLoad: 7c920000 7c9b6000   ntdll.dll
ModLoad: 7c800000 7c91e000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll
ModLoad: 10000000 10021000   R:\home\STools\MIPS\mips_iasim-1.1.1\bin\Windows32\libRuntimeLoader.dll
ModLoad: 77be0000 77c38000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
ModLoad: 10480000 1057e000   C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4053_x-ww_d014c028\MSVCP80D.dll
ModLoad: 10200000 10321000   C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4053_x-ww_d014c028\MSVCR80D.dll
ModLoad: 78130000 781cb000   C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC80.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.6195_x-ww_44262b86\MSVCR80.dll
ModLoad: 77d10000 77da0000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
ModLoad: 77ef0000 77f39000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
(18c58.184f0): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
eax=00251eb4 ebx=7ffde000 ecx=00000007 edx=00000080 esi=00251f48 edi=00251eb4
eip=7c92120e esp=0012fb20 ebp=0012fc94 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000202
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for ntdll.dll - 
ntdll!DbgBreakPoint:
7c92120e cc              int     3
0:000> g
ModLoad: 008b0000 00a20000   R:\home\STools\MIPS\mips_iasim-1.1.1\bin\Windows32\libOVPsimMIPS.dll
ModLoad: 00a20000 00bc6000   R:\home\STools\MIPS\mips_iasim-1.1.1\bin\Windows32\mipsiasim11.dll
ModLoad: 5fdd0000 5fe25000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\NETAPI32.dll
ModLoad: 77da0000 77e49000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
ModLoad: 77e50000 77ee3000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\RPCRT4.dll
ModLoad: 77fc0000 77fd1000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\Secur32.dll
ModLoad: 76320000 76367000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\comdlg32.dll
ModLoad: 5d170000 5d20a000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\COMCTL32.dll
ModLoad: 7d590000 7dd84000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHELL32.dll
ModLoad: 77f40000 77fb6000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
ModLoad: 71a40000 71a4b000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\WSOCK32.dll
ModLoad: 71a20000 71a37000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2_32.dll
ModLoad: 71a10000 71a18000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2HELP.dll
ModLoad: 65100000 65111000   R:\home\STools\MIPS\mips_iasim-1.1.1\bin\Windows32\pthreadGC2-w32.dll
ModLoad: 76d30000 76d48000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
(18c58.184f0): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.
eax=00000000 ebx=5d170000 ecx=0012ee24 edx=0000004c esi=7c813029 edi=00000000
eip=7c92e470 esp=0012ee2c ebp=0012ee50 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00010206
ntdll!KiUserCallbackDispatcher+0x10:
7c92e470 ff1490          call    dword ptr [eax+edx*4] ds:0023:00000130=????????
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\WINDOWS\system32\COMCTL32.dll - 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll - 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for R:\home\STools\MIPS\mips_iasim-1.1.1\bin\Windows32\libRuntimeLoader.dll -
```

The DLLs at disk R are 3rdparty libraries.

Comment: Try to call LoadLibrary for that DLL in an empty app.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I tried with LoadLibrary to load the libraries manually, there's no problem.